# Unknown variable direction in object.direction | Game Maker

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

This is my first question on a forum so please forgive any mistakes I may have made.

I am trying to make a game similar to the classic "Asteroids". I am trying to split the asteroids in two when a laser hits them. The following code is in an event in the asteroid object that is triggered when the laser collides with the asteroid.

```
inst1 = instance_create(x, y, medium1)
with (inst1) {
    speed = random_range(5,8)
    direction = laser.direction + random_range(0, 90)
}

inst2 = instance_create(x, y, medium1)
with (inst2) {
    speed = random_range(5,8)
    direction = laser.direction - random_range(0 ,90)
}
```

My issue occurs seemingly randomly. The game loads normally and the asteroids will split several times (sometimes 3-4, sometimes I can almost go through an entire game without encountering it) as I want them to, then this error pops up.

> ERROR in
>   action number 1
>   of Collision Event with object laser
>   for object big1:
>
> Error in code at line 4:
>          direction = laser.direction + random_range(0, 90)
>               ^
>   at position 26: Unknown variable direction

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is `laser`? A variable or an object's name?

Comment: it is an object's name, says so in the post

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`with` statement](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_18_with.html), which makes code be executed by a given instance but you must be aware of instance reference variables: at line 4 the `direction` variable is `inst1`'s, but the reference `laser` is not the laser object it collided with, but the reference to *all* `laser` instances. It means, if there's at least one `laser` instance, its direction will be referenced correctly, otherwise the script is trying to read an unexisting variable (since there are no `laser`s).

You can easily fix your code by using the special keyword [`other`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/keywords.html):

```
// Create asteroid fragments
inst1 = instance_create(x, y, medium1);
inst2 = instance_create(x, y, medium1);

// Update fragment variables
inst1.speed = random_range(5,8);
inst1.direction = other.direction + random_range(0, 90);

inst2.speed = random_range(5,8);
inst2.direction = other.direction - random_range(0, 90);
```

Since we are executing code inside the *Collision Event*, the special keyword `other` lets us reference the *other* instance that our *current* instance has collided with. So, `other.direction` is not any laser's direction, but the very laser that hit our asteroid.

The reason I'm not using the `with` construction is because the keyword `other` can be used there too, but with a different meaning:

```
with (inst1) {
    speed = random_range(5,8);
    direction = other.direction + random_range(0, 90);
}
```

Here, `other` references to the asteroid instance, because it is the one invoking the `with` construction. If we want to reference the `laser` we are colliding with, we must write `other.other`, so its direction will be `other.other.direction`, but that's quite confusing (and maybe wrong too).

Comment: I thought that you don't need to reference `other.other`, because other meaning has swapped. so you could call the laser object directly.